# Fixed field of function field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, function-fields

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0$ and $L = K(Y)$. For every $a \in K$, we define $\sigma_a \in \operatorname{Aut}_K(L)$ via $\sigma_a(Y) = Y + a$. Let $H = \{\sigma_a\; | \; a \in \mathbb{F}_p\}$. Show that $L^H = K(Z)$ where $L^H$ is the fixed field of $H$ and $Z = Y^p - Y$.

I don't really know where to start with either $L^H \subset K(Z)$ or $K(Z) \subset L^H$. If $a \in K(Z)$, I have to show that $\sigma(a) = a$ for every $\sigma \in H$ but how exactly can I do this?. For the other inclusion, I'm kinda confused what it means, that $a \in K(Z)$. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see that for the inclusion $K(Z)\subset L^H$, you only need to show that $Z\in L^H$?

Comment: Show that $K(Z)\subset L^H$ by showing $\sigma_a(Z)=Z$ for all $a\in\Bbb F_p$ and then conclude $K(Z)=L^H$ using a degree argument

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes, thank you!

As for leoli1, great hint, thank you!